# Angular combobox with index variable acessible outside of ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically i want to display and index variable in another part of my template without using variables inside my component, to simplify my code.

**component.ts**

```
items:[{name:'foo',val:100},{name:'boo',val:200},{name:'doo',val:300}];
```

**html**

```
<select *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
   <option value="i+1">{{i+1}} {{item}}</option>
</select>

...thing and another itens
<!--here i want to get the value of selected value of for and the selected index-->
<p>{{i.value}} {{item.value}}</p>
```

Its possible or its better set and on change event in component passing the variable with #selected to component and then get it after selected ?

Comment: You can use a ngModel on the select or a reactiveForm, but the sample you gave won't work like that.

Comment: oh, like formGroup.get('controlName').value  ?